# How do I get cmd code to run from a .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to make a .bat file that runs these lines of code, but I can’t figure that out.

```
bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING OFF 

shutdown -r
```

Comment: What have you tried? Batch scripts are just a list of commands to run and the order to run them in. I'm downvoting because it's obvious that you didn't even try to put them in a script.

Answer (score 0):

`Create` a text file

`rename` the file to `Example.bat`

`edit` the file and place your code

`Save` the file and then run it

**Congratulations, I have become a programmer**